# Как построить масштабируемость строк в запросе?

Tags: jmeter

К примеру, есть числа от 1 до 100000, которые нужно зарандомить.
`${__Random(1,100000,)}`
Можно ли применить к рандому джметра масштабируемость. Я имею в виду параметр, который бы увеличивал рандом последнего числа со 100000 в 10 раз, в 100 раз больше, и так далее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `100000` на функцию [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) и делайте там любые арифметические операции

```
${__Random(1,${__jexl3(100000 * 10,)},)}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[функции](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) можно использовать где угодно, в том числе внутри других функций, только не забывайте экранировать запятые

Более подробная информация: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)